# Azure App Service custom authentication getting System.ArgumentNullException: "Value cannot be null" "Parameter name: provider"

Tags: .net, azure, azure-mobile-services

I have a simple dot net mobile app with custom authentication following the example at (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-dotnet-backend-how-to-use-server-sdk#custom-auth)

I have an endpoint for generating the JWT Token
https://test2ixresearcher.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/custom?username=ade%40ixcompany.com&password=a
(the user name and password are not checked, you can enter anything)

This creates a token which I use to call a secured endpoint with the provided token in the X-ZUMO-AUTH header: https://test2ixresearcher.azurewebsites.net/api/SecuredData
- Calling the end point with an incorrect token or token missing returns a 401, as expected
- Calling the end point with the token just created generates a 500 with the following message, no expected

--Start Error message--
Application: 2018-09-22T23:12:20  PID[5520] Critical    System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Application: Parameter name: provider
Application:    at Microsoft.Azure.AppService.Authentication.EasyAuthTokenStore.d__7.MoveNext()
Application: --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

--End Error message--
I also have an unsecured endpoint and this works without any problems.
https://test2ixresearcher.azurewebsites.net/api/UnSecuredData

I have deployed at least 4 other apps with this model and this is the first instance of having this error. The error appears in the authentication, it seems to successfully validate the token issuer and pull out the user, and it fails before hitting my code.

My code can be found at https://github.com/antitheos/publictesting/tree/master/TestAzureCustomLogin

This is happening when published to azure in a new app service created through the portal or Visual Studio. I have old app services working but I afraid to trying publishing to them in case i break live apps the are working.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you found out what the issue is with this? We're experiencing the same thing. Have deployed the same Api/mobile app to 2 environments with no issues, but the 3rd environment we're seeing the same thing. We've completed deleted and recreated with minimum configuration and still no dice.

Comment: @razaross444 I have a ticket open with Microsoft, the support engineer could recreate the issue and is working with the product team.  When I find out more I will keep you updated.  Not sure if opening another ticket with Microsoft would help expedite things, but you could try.

Comment: @@Ade I was just about to open a ticket as well. We've been running this successfully on Free tiers in West US. This is the first time we've tried setting it up on a paid tier (S2) in Central U.S.  I've copied the environment details from Kudu on each environment into files and diffing them to see if anything stands out. I'll also let you know if we find a solution. Thanks!

Comment: Opened a critical level ticket and just got off the phone with them. They have the url for your post here and will try to find your ticket as well (I guess by searching for some of the info you've posted here) so both of them get higher visibility. If you find resolution before I do, would you mind letting me know? Thanks!

Comment: I got a response back, it appears app services now have a setting called WEBSITE_AUTH_RUNTIME_VERSION. In my checks I could find the setting in new app services.  In older app services that work as expected this setting is missing. I found the setting under Kudu. I am going to test what happens when I remove the setting and report back my findings.

Comment: Thx! Gabe, who I think is assigned to your ticket contacted me as well with the same info. I installed IIS Manager extension via Kudu and added this transform to remove it but it's not working. <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <system.webServer>
    <runtime xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing">
      <environmentVariables xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing">
        <remove name="APPSETTING_WEBSITE_AUTH_RUNTIME_VERSION" />
      </environmentVariables>
    </runtime>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>

Comment: If you figure out how to remove it, pls let me know.

Comment: I told MS how I did not know how to remove the setting since it only appears in Kudu, I have been told to hold tight.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, Microsoft found the issue!

The product team found a regression bug and it's now slated for fixing in the next release for about a month from now. In the meantime, you can resolve it with the following steps.

1. Open Azure portal, navigate to your App Service
2. Click on Resource Explorer blade
3. Under your site node, expand the config node and then click authSettings.
4. In the top pane, ensure you have read/write selected.
5. Click Edit button
6. Modify the runtimeVersion to = 0.0.0
7. Click Put
8. Click Post
9. Restart your website.

[image]

Comment: Tnx! that works, btw more than one months passed from the OP but I faced the problem today.

Comment: Figures... when they said one month, I thought "yeah, right". lol