# Azure App Service OpenID authentication with Auth0 fails: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'rawToken')

Tags: azure, openid-connect, auth0, azure-appservice, azure-authentication

I'm creating an App Service in Azure and trying to wire up OpenID Connect authentication with Auth0.

**Problem:**

Auth0's login page pops up, I can login. Auth0 redirects browser to my app's callback URL with the Authorization Code. The app returns HTTP 500 internal server error.

`...easyauth_docker.log` shows that Azure Authentication Middleware thrown the following exception:

...
`System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'rawToken') 2021-12-13T15:40:26.451788664Z    at Microsoft.Azure.AppService.Middleware.ModuleUtils.ThrowIfNullOrEmpty(String argName, String argValue) in /EasyAuth/Microsoft.Azure.AppService.Middleware.Modules/ModuleUtils.cs:line 867 2021-12-13T15:40:26.451799664Z    at Microsoft.Azure.AppService.Middleware.ModuleUtils.ValidateJwt(String siteName, String rawToken, TokenValidationParameters parameters, String provider, Boolean useLegacyClaims, JwtSecurityToken& jwt, Exception& handledException, Boolean isLoginAction) in /EasyAuth/Microsoft.Azure.AppService.Middleware.Modules/ModuleUtils.cs:line 567`
...

**Implementation:**

- Created App Service in Azure with Linux/Node.js. The app is available without authentication at: `https://<MY_APP>.azurewebsites.net`. I can debug it with VS Code too.
- Created an Auth0 Application of type Regular Web Application (Authorization Code Grant). Added Allowed Callback URL: `https://<MY_APP>.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/auth0/callback`
- Enabled Authentication on App Service. Added OpenID Connect Identity Provider. Specified Metadata URL: `https://<MY_AUTH0_DOMAIN>/.well-known/openid-configuration` (URL works from browser). Copied Client ID and Client Secret from Auth0 page.

**Additional info:**

- Auth0's log contains two entries: Success Login and Successful Exchange: "Authorization Code for Access Token"
- After login page, the redirected call does not reach my node.js code (checked in debugger).

Comment: Any success on that? I'm having the same issue here.

Answer (score 0):

I was having exactly the same problem even though I was using [Ory Hydra](https://www.ory.sh/docs/hydra) instead of [Auth0](https://auth0.com/) to authenticate. In my case, I realize my Authentication app wasn't sending the `id_token` back with the `authorization_token`. Checking the list of the **Common Problems** I found some referencing [OpenID Connect ID Token missing](https://www.ory.sh/docs/hydra/debug#openid-connect-id-token-missing).

In my case it was the 4th option, because I forgot to send the correct scopes in my consent app:

> 4. Your consent app didn't send granted_scope: ["openid"] or when
>    accepting the consent request.

So, I believe that if your authentication app is not sending the `id_token`, **Azure Authentication Middleware** will throw the exact same error. Hope it helps someone with the same problem.

Answer (score -1):

Please check if your cause is among few of known cases:

1. Try to  restart your web app and check if that makes any difference.
2. According to Node.js [best practices and troubleshooting- Azure App Service | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-nodejs-best-practices-and-troubleshoot-guide#my-node-application-does-not-start)

> If your application is returning 500 Errors when it starts, there
> could be a few reasons:
>
> 1. Node.exe is not present at the correct location. Check nodeProcessCommandLine setting.
> 2. Main script file is not present at the correct location. Check web.config and make sure the name of the main script file in the
>    handlers section matches the main script file.

It may also be due to  incompatible nuget packages.

3. App services has a setting `WEBSITE_AUTH_RUNTIME_VERSION`. This can be a possible cause:
   Try to modify the runtime version of app service . See [.net - Azure App Service - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52469188/azure-app-service-custom-authentication-getting-system-argumentnullexception-v)
   .Then restart the process.

For Linux apps, add an app setting called `WEBSITE_WEBDEPLOY_USE_SCM` and set it to `true` in your app: [Reference](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-cloud@latest/actions/deployment/deploying-to-your-cloud-provider/deploying-to-azure-app-service)

In some cases where not necessary ,removing docker connector will solve the issues related to null reference exceptions.

**References:**

1. [node.js - similar type of error - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56394772/error-while-trying-to-pull-azure-key-vault-from-azure-function-value-cannot-be)
2. [Azure Functions and App Service Authentication with Auth0 and other OpenID Connect providers (anthonychu.ca)](https://anthonychu.ca/post/azure-functions-app-service-openid-connect-auth0/#:%7E:text=%20Azure%20Functions%20and%20App%20Service%20Authentication%20with,function%20app%27s%20Configuration...%205%20Resources.%20%20More%20)

You can raise a support request if issue remains : from overview page of azure app service portal > Support + troubleshoot  > New Support Request.

Comment: 1. I tried several times. 2. If there were problems there I suggest the app would not work without authentication either, but it does. 3. I'll try, it is a Linux app by the way. Meanwhile I've written the authentication within the node.js app using express and passport, and it works fine.